# How to add automountServiceAccountToken: false using Helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, k8s-serviceaccount

I have been trying to add automountServiceAccountToken: false into deployment using helm but my changes are reflecting inside deployment in kubernetes.

I tried below in **helpers.tpl**

```
{{- "<chart-name>.automountserviceaccounttoken" }}
{{- default "false" .Values.automountserviceaccounttoken.name }}
{{- end }}
```

**in app-deployment.yaml**

```
automountServiceAccountToken: {{- include "<chart-name>.automountserviceaccounttoken" . }}
```

**in values.yaml**

```
automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

But I can't see the changes. Please guide

Comment: Having made these changes locally, are you running `helm upgrade` to deploy them?  Does the added line show up in `helm template` output?

Comment: helm template is okay. I am trying to fix security things. so we need to disable service account mount.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with following troubleshooting steps

1. In the `helpers.tpl` file you are taking the
   `automountserviceaccounttoken` value from the **values.yaml**. In
   `values.yaml` you metnioned `automountserviceaccounttoken:false` but
   in the tpl file you are accesing the value like
   `automountserviceaccounttoken.name` there is no attribute called
   name under automountserviceaccounttoken in values file. Although you
   are using default value in function sometimes it may not include it.
   So correct he value in values.yaml.
2. Debug the deployed heml chart by using a command `$helm template template-name`. It will download the generated helm template along
   with values. Check whether your desired values are reflecting or
   not.
3. In case you are redeploying the chart try upgrading it by `$helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART]` and make sure your values are reflecting.
4. Before installing the helm chart running with dry-run will give us
   the templates with compiled values. So using dry run will helps to
   confirm the templates. Command for dry-run `$helm install chart-name . --dry-run`

Fore more information refer to [official document](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-upgrade-and-helm-rollback-upgrading-a-release-and-recovering-on-failure)

Comment: Hi @Ravindra did you get a chance to look at the answer?is it helpful?Happy to assist further if you have any doubts?